# Silent Install Weblogic in a Vagrant VM

Tags: bash, vagrant, weblogic

When executing the command `java -jar /opt/TAR/fmw_12.2.1.0_wls.jar -silent -responseFile /opt/TAR/wls.rsp -invPtrLoc /opt/TAR/oraInst.loc`to download Weblogic, I get the following errors:

```
[ERROR] Data Insufficient to start Install.
[ERROR] Select one and only one Install Type. Any one of the variables SOFTWARE ONLY TYPE,BASIC TYPE or ADVANCED                                 
[ERROR] Rule_VDiskSpace_Error. Aborting Install
```

I have passed all the checks including enough swap space and temp space. I have also tried to increase more swap space by doing the following

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=/myswap count=3000 bs=MiB
$ chmod 600 /myswap
$ mkswap /myswap
$ swapon /myswap
```

My `wls.rsp` file looks like this

```
[ENGINE]
Response File Version=1.0.0.0.0
[GENERIC]
ORACLE_HOME/opt/weblogic/wls12.2.1.2.0
INSTALL_TYPE=WebLogic Server
MYORACLESUPPORT_USERNAME=
MYORACLESUPPORT_PASSWORD=<SECURE VALUE>
DECLINE_SECURITY_UPDATES=true
SECURITY_UPDATES_VIA_MYORACLESUPPORT=false
PROXY_HOST=
PROXY_PORT=
PROXY_USER=
PROXY_PWD=<SECURE VALUE>
COLLECTOR_SUPPORTHUB_URL=
```

and `oraInst.loc` looks like this

```
inventory_loc=/opt/weblogic/oraInventory
inst_group=weblogic
```

What can fix those three errors?

Comment: the documentation states: java -jar distribution_name.jar -silent -responseFile file [-options] [()*] maybe you need to omit the oraInst.loc file? https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/core/OUIRF/silent.htm#OUIRF334

Comment: @EmreTürkiş This is what I need as paramaters: `java -jar <installer file> -silent -respFile <response file location> -invPtrLoc <absolute path to the file>` with `inventory_loc` and `inst_group` paramters within `oraInst.loc`

Comment: have you tried chmod'ing 775 to those files? there may be an access-right issue maybe. and could you please paste the whole output of it

Comment: please make sure your system complies with the specs here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23104_01/sysreqs1221/sysrs.htm#CHDCDIAI

Answer (score 2):

Your response file has some issues - see fixed

```
[ENGINE]
Response File Version=1.0.0.0.0
[GENERIC]
DECLINE_AUTO_UPDATES=true
ORACLE_HOME=/opt/weblogic/wls12.2.1.2.0
INSTALL_TYPE=WebLogic Server
MYORACLESUPPORT_USERNAME=
MYORACLESUPPORT_PASSWORD=
DECLINE_SECURITY_UPDATES=true
SECURITY_UPDATES_VIA_MYORACLESUPPORT=false
PROXY_HOST=
PROXY_PORT=
PROXY_USER=
PROXY_PWD=
COLLECTOR_SUPPORTHUB_URL=
```

You need to add a value for `DECLINE_AUTO_UPDATES` if you set to false, you need to add [other parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12212/lcm/OUIRF/GUID-2DBCEBB2-165B-4976-A3B8-9B25C30BAC2B.htm#OUIRF329)

the `<SECURE VALUE>` is just a template - if you dont set username you dont need password, just leave blank

Comment: There was some problem in my script that kept overwritting `wls.rsp` leaving it empty. I updated my question.

Comment: are you sure you have `set('ListenPort', 8110)` and not with `setListenPort` somehow as the error suggests ? note its better to have `exit()` method at the end of python script

Comment: It's written properly. I don't understand how it produces that error.

Comment: Nvm I found my problem, I was missing a few lines

Comment: Need to add a missing '=': ORACLE_HOME=/opt/weblogic/wls12.2.1.2.0 (too small a change to edit)

Comment: @Caleb Good catch, Thank you! I've made the update and added the '=' sign

Answer (score 1):

try to use

```
-ignoreSysPrereqs
```

so your command will be

```
java -jar /opt/TAR/fmw_12.2.1.0_wls.jar -ignoreSysPrereqs -silent -responseFile /opt/TAR/wls.rsp -invPtrLoc /opt/TAR/oraInst.loc
```

https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/oui-silent-installations